# Objects to Handler (ashx) using JSON.stringify()

Tags: stringify

I'm trying to pass following objects to `Handler` (ashx) using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var obj1 = {
users: { usId: 1, usName: "XX"},
dept:{ chId: 1, chName: "AA"}
},

obj2 = {
    users: { usId: 2, usName: "YY" },
    dept:{ chId: 2, chName: "BB" }
},
obj3 = {
    users3: { usId: 3, usName: "ZZ" },
    dept: { chId: 3, chName: "CC" }
};

var obj = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
    url: "Handler.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { Data: JSON.stringify(obj) },
    success: alert("Suceess")
    });
});
```

I got the JSON string using `context.Request.["data"]`. Now how can I add the above values into my properties and class? My class structure looks like:

```
public class testclass
{
   public List<User> users {get;set;}
   public List<Dept> dept{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37069/JSON-serialization-and-de-serialization-in-WCF-Dat

Comment: it has a single request hence in my case has multiple request i.e, array. I could not able to add array using the above method.